Get only Actuated joints position/velocity as output port from `MultiBodyPlant`?
so I'm trying to import an Quadrupedal robot with an arm in to the drake system. The robot have URDF and mesh files (ROS format) that I have converted so that it's imported properly, with transmission tag added in the URDF file that was missing.
I'm trying to run a basic PIDController example, but I'm currently stuck. as not all the joints have actuation in them, but PIDController expect the input dim to be of 2 * output dim. The number of actuators is 14 so PIDController expect 28, but the system have total state_output_port() of 47  (somehow a prime number?). Intuitively, I guess I should get the Position/Velocity of those 14 Joints with Actuators on it, but I'm struggling to find how to do it?
model = parser.AddModelsFromUrl(xgo_mini)
plant: MultibodyPlant # contains the model

plant.get_actuation_input_port().size() == len(plant.GetActuatedJointIndicies(model)
# size is 14, as expected: 3 actuator per leg + 2 for arm = 3*4 + 2 = 14
plant.get_state_output_port().size()
# This is 47... somehow.
controller: PiDController # initialized with 14 dim Kp/Kd/Ki
builder: DiagramBuilder
builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(), controller.get_input_port_estimated_state()

RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched vector sizes while connecting output port state of System plant (size 47) to input port estimated_state of System controller (size 28)

The original URDF file is from this robot (but modified for Drake) https://github.com/sskorol/xgo_ros Thank you in advance

The answer from This other question (or modification thereof) worked, so maybe I should close it with that
